# Visualforce Report Page with some graphs

Tags: visualforce, graph

I‘m very new with salesforce and visualforce.

Our CEO has requested a big volume of reports with visual graphs. I tried a lot with the standard reports and dashboards but they are often not very flexible.

First I began to collect the values and put it into the graph. This works, but first time I ran into the Governor limit of 50.000. I solved this problem with the "read-only" option. Now I have the next problem, I run sometimes, Not every time, into CPU time Limit exceeded.

Here is my code. if I group the selection is that helpful?

```
    public void getActualvalues(){   

    String SelectClause = 'SELECT BWS1__c, BWS2__c, Date__c FROM Sales__c';
    
    List <String> WhereClauses = new List <String>();   
    
    IF (SelectedUserId.contains('Region')) { 
        WhereClauses.add('Region__c = \'' + SelectedUserId + '\'');
    } 
    IF (!SelectedUserId.contains('Region')) {
        WhereClauses.Add('Salesman __r.Id = \'' + SelectedUserId + '\'');
    }
    WhereClauses.Add('BWS1__c != NULL AND Calendar_Year(Date__c) = 2020'); 
    String WhereClause = ' WHERE ' + String.join(WhereClauses, ' AND ');  
    String SQL = SelectClause + WhereClause;
    
        System.Debug('>>>> the value of SQL is ' + SQL);
    
    List <Sales__c> CY_SalesList = Database.query(SQL);

        FOR(Sales__c CY_Sales : CY_SalesList){        

            IF(CY_Sales.Date__c.month() == 1) {CY_01_BWS1 += CY_Sales.BWS1__c;}
   

 IF(CY_Sales.Date__c.month() == 2) {CY_02_BWS1 += CY_Sales.BWS1__c;} 

    IF(CY_Sales.Date__c.month() == 3) {CY_03_BWS1 += CY_Sales.BWS1__c;}
```

for each month....
}

```
Public List <SelectOption> getListOfUser() {
    List <User> Users = [SELECT Id, LastName, FirstName FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE ORDER BY LastName];
    List <SelectOption> UserOptionList = new List <SelectOption>();
    UserOptionList.add (new SelectOption ('',''));
    UserOptionList.add (new SelectOption ('North', 'Region North'));        
    UserOptionList.add (new SelectOption ('East', 'Region East'));   
    UserOptionList.add (new SelectOption ('West', 'Region West'));    
    FOR (User u : Users) {
        UserOptionList.add (new SelectOption(u.Id, u.LastName + ' ' + u.FirstName));
    }
    RETURN UserOptionList;
}
```

I checked the logfile and the first month january works fine but the switch to the second month does'nt work. I think that is the reason.

```
Decimal[] values = new Decimal[11];

FOR(Integer i = 1; i <= values.size(); i++) 
{
    values[i] = 0;
    
    FOR(Sales__c CY_Sales : CY_SalesList)
        {        
            Integer Mo = CY_Sales.Date__c.month();
            values[Mo] += CY_Sales.BWS1__c;
        }
}
```

**EDIT 15 July**

My new code included now an array for the both years which were inputed at the page and a loop which loop thru the years. this works fine so far, but I don't know how can I store the values of both years in a variable.

```
    public void getActualvalues(){   
    
 Integer[] arrayOfYear = new List<Integer>();

arrayOfYear.add(Integer.valueof(Selected_Year_1));
arrayOfYear.add(Integer.valueof(Selected_Year_2));
    
for (Integer j = 0; j<arrayOfYear.size(); j++) {
   system.debug('Values In Array: '+arrayOfYear[j]);
   
    String SelectClause = 'SELECT BWS1__c, Date__c FROM Sales__c';
    
    List <String> WhereClauses = new List <String>();   
    
    IF (SelectedUserId == ('North') || SelectedUserId == ('South') || SelectedUserId == ('East') || SelectedUserId == ('West') || SelectedUserId == ('Southwest')) { 
        WhereClauses.add('Salesman__r.Region__c = \'' + SelectedUserId + '\'');
    } 
    IF (SelectedUserId != ('North') && SelectedUserId != ('South') && SelectedUserId != ('East') && SelectedUserId != ('West') && SelectedUserId != ('Southwest') && SelectedUserId != Null) {
        WhereClauses.Add('Salesman__r.Id = \'' + SelectedUserId + '\'');
    }
    IF (SelectedUserId == ('')) {
        WhereClauses.Add('');
    }    
 
    WhereClauses.Add('BWS1__c != NULL AND Calendar_Year(Date__c) = ' + arrayOfYear[j]); 
    String WhereClause = ' WHERE ' + String.join(WhereClauses, ' AND ');  
    String SQL = SelectClause + WhereClause;
       
    List <Sales__c> CY_SalesList = Database.query(SQL);

    Decimal[] values = new Decimal[12];
    
    FOR(Integer i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) 
        { values[i] = 0; }
           
            FOR(Sales__c CY_Sales : CY_SalesList)
                {        
                    Integer Mo = CY_Sales.Date__c.month();
                    values[Mo-1] += CY_Sales.BWS1__c;
                }
                                    
        CY_BWS1 = values[0];
        CY_BWS2 = values[1];
        CY_BWS3 = values[2];
        CY_BWS4 = values[3];
        CY_BWS5 = values[4];
        CY_BWS6 = values[5];
        CY_BWS7 = values[6];
        CY_BWS8 = values[7];
        CY_BWS9 = values[8];
        CY_BWS10 = values[9];
        CY_BWS11 = values[10];
        CY_BWS12 = values[11];      
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite your for loop as follows

```
Decimal[] values = new Decimal[12];
for (Integer i = 0; i < values.size(); i++); {values[i] = 0;}

for (Sales__c CY_Sales : CY_SalesList){        
    if (CY_Sales_Date__c == null) {continue;} // assume some recs have no date
    Integer mo = CY_Sales.Date__c.month();
    values[mo-1] += CY_Sales__c.BWS1__c;
}

CY_01_BWS1 = values[0];
CY_02_BWS1 = values[1];
.. for all 12 months
```

This way, you don't do 12 ifs on every row retrieved; nor re-executing the `month()` method 12 times

Now, if there are a ton of rows being retrieved, even this optimization will run out of CPU time and you'll need to think of async solutions to construct the data on a scheduled basis.

You should also look at Lightning Dashboards which have very powerful widgets for visualization that might solve your issue without any code.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've changed the code but now I always ran into **Attempt to de-reference a null object** at the line "values[Mo] += CY_Sales.BWS1__c;
". I've added the code at the end of the origianlpost.

Comment: @Sascha - silly typos on my part, see correction

Comment: great it works. last question, how can I add the year also? I have two fields at my visualforce (Year1 and Year2) to compare the years. First time I loop thru all sales with Year1 and the Month Date and then the same with Year2. I have to change my WhereClause **WhereClauses.Add('Date__c.year = \'' + Year1 + '\'');**

Comment: please use [edit] and change your original question to include the latest code, snippet of the VF and what you are doing for year in both places.  It is too hard for me to speculate what you are trying to do based on the above comment.

Comment: you are right. I added my new code to the original post "EDIT 15. July" The CEO have the possibility to choose two years to compare. my code loop thru the sales of the two years, but i don't know how can I store the values.

Comment: I'm still not following even with revised code.  What is the VF result supposed to look like with the 2 years?

Comment: I need in my chart the sales of the selected years, for each year one line. My array ran thru the both years, but I think it overwrite the values from the first year.

Comment: so -- I answered the question about CPU time; you can choose to accept it or not. I suggest posting a new question with your code AND VisualForce AND picture of what you want the chart to look like  -- the multi-year issue is a separate question from your original question. Please see [ask]